# layer nav : add multiple value to one product attribute

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

Is it possible to add multiple values to one attribute in magento which will be sortable in the layered nav?

here an example :

atttribute "volt" which have : 2V, 6V and 12V

product 1 
volt : 2V

product 2
volt : 2V, 12V

product 3
volt : 2V,6V, 12V

so, the layered nav shows the attribute "volt" with 2V, 6V and 12V.....and once you click on 12V, only product 2 and 3 show up. With 2V, product 1,2 and 3 shup up and so on.

do you know how I can get this result in magento?

thanks!

Comment: Did you try to configure a multiselect attribute with the values and layered navigation activated?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible with a default Magento install. You can set up your product attribute like this

[image: volt-attribute]

which will display Volt as part of the layered navigation, allowing you to filter by any of the individual values.

The important settings here are
`Catalog Input Type = Multiple Select`
and
`Use in Layered Navigation = Filterable`

`Filterable (with results)` will only show filters that would result in a product match

`Filterable (no results)` will include filters that would result in no product.

For example if you had set up the attribute as 2V,6V,12V and 20V with results would only show the options 2V,6V and 12V - No results would include the 20V.

Comment: thanks fooman,  I just wondering how we can import the date to the product to create the association.  Can we only put a "," between the value ?

Comment: I am not quite sure how importing date is in relation to the above question. I believe to import multi select values from a csv file they need to be separated by <space>,<space>